# Android views layout

Tags: java, android, layout, imagebutton

I took some code from an example application and I need help rearranging it. I'm trying to make a simple mp3 player. Everything works on a small screen. However, when it is rotated or if the screen size is bigger, the layout is all off. I don't know why this is happening. Please help. Thanks so much. My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:onClick="forward"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:onClick="rewind"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:onClick="pause"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:text="@string/inital_Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:text="@string/inital_Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:text="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:onClick="previous"

                        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@drawable/go_next_black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBar1"

        android:onClick="next"
        android:src="@drawable/go_next_black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: I tried to add fill_parent to it, but it doesn't work

Comment: You should be a little bit more specific.What exactly did you want to make and what do you see instead?

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple mp3 player with a left and right arrow for switching songs. Everything right now works on my phone. But when I tried it on a different screen sized phone, the layout is off. The right arrow does not expand to a larger size and and rewind button extends. I tried changing the layout_width to fill_parent and it doesn't help. I even tried to set to center and it still doesn't work. Hopefully you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To manage layouts possibly to run on all the devices, please use LinearLayout with layout_weight functionality.